# Maintain ResultReceiver for IntentService across Orientation Change without Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have been doing some work writing clients to execute (potentially) long-running operations against a REST api.

My first iteration used an IntentService with a ResultReceiver to communicate back to the Activity.  After this, I implemented a client using AsyncTask.  Finally, a third client extended the AsyncTask client to use Fragments so I could handle things like orientation changes.

Now I'd like to revist my first two iterations and "orientation-change proof" them.  Is this possible without using fragments?  I have tried to use onSaveInstanceState / onCreate to save/recreate the ResultReceiver, but it doesn't seem to work (and this does not suprise me).

I'm not anti-fragment, just wondering if there is a pre-fragment pattern for accomplishing this (something to do with BroadcastReceiver perhaps)?  Or is this just a known pre-fragment issue?

Comment: Personally, I'd switch to something other than `ResultReceiver`, such as `LocalBroadcastManager` or a third-party event bus like Square's Otto or greenrobot's EventBus.

Comment: I like each of these possibilities in varying degrees.  Is there a non-fragment solution which uses ResultReceiver, or is this a deficiency and one of the reasons to look elsewhere?

Comment: Since I have never liked `ResultReceiver`, I have not explored your scenario, sorry.

Comment: I've taken a crack at implementing this using Otto, but i'm having some issues (specifically - the events I publish in the Service are swallowed by the bus, never to be heard from again).  Is there a good (succinct) example of how to do this? The ones I've seen don't help.

Comment: Make sure that you register your objects implementing `@Subscribe` annotations via `register()` on the bus. Unfortunately, I have not yet published any bus samples, though that's on my to-do list for sometime in the next few months.

Comment: Yeah, I did all that.  I suspect it has to do with the bus. I'm implementing that as a singleton and I had to include some Looper code (lifted from somewhere else) to quell ThreadEnforcement issues.  It's a little suspect to say the least. So a Bus example would help a-lot.

Comment: Using EventBus had it's own issues. It appears events get "lost" during orientation changes and I had to add-in some event re-send capability.  Even then, it didn't *always* handle the changes gracefully.